# How to move an object 500 pixels only at a different speed at random intervals?

Tags: c#, object

I'm trying to write a piece of code that will allow an object to "dash" for 500 pixels at random. I've got the random time down, it's the specific distance that I've got an issue with.

This is for an assignment where I'm supposed to research how to do it, but I have had no luck in finding anything. I've tried creating an incremental variable, but that doesn't count quick enough, I'm sure it's related to this equation for the movement of the object: xPosition += xSpeed * xDirection;. I just can't figure it out. The code does show some other functions as well, like reducing the speed to the previous speed once the 500 pixels has been covered.

The other problem is that the grid I'm working on has positive and negative numbers, so I'm not sure, but will I also need to account for that as well?

```
       if (xSpeed >= 10)
       {
            if (xPosition < 0)
            {
                distance = distance + 1;
            }
            if (xPosition > 0)
            {
                distance = distance + 1;
            }
        }

        if (collisionNum == ranCollision - 1)
        {
            dashPosStart = xPosition;
        }


        // Method for stopping dash
        if (distance >= 500)

        {
            while (xSpeed > startSpeed)
            {
                xSpeed--;
            }

            ySpeed = xSpeed / 2;

        }

        if (distance == 500)
        {
            dashPosFin = xPosition;
        }


        xPosition += xSpeed * xDirection; // Horizontal movement
        yPosition += ySpeed * yDirection; // Vertical movement
```

The distance should be counting every pixel but it seems to be counting much slower than that, and slower than 60 times a second (the speed the program works). I've been trying to work this out for days now and just can't get my head round it. Any help/ advice would be great! Thanks.

Comment: You should work in pixels (or units) per second. When you update the screen and check the delta time between the current and the previous update. (using a `Stopwatch`) Use that to multiply it with the desired speed. (this will handle the fluctuation in updates/second)

Comment: the amount of pixels you travel in a direction is dependant on speed, if you say travel 200px/second (assuming you have 60hz display) you travel 3.33 pixels per frame

Answer (score 1):

You're always incrementing distance by one; thus, the dash will always take 500 frames to complete, rather than a distance of 500 pixels.

The shortest fix would be to increment distance by the dash speed each frame (make sure to handle negative values appropriately).

Comment: Thanks for that! I just knew it would be a simple solution and I was trying to overthink it. It worked perfectly.